# Magento 2: Custom customer attribute not saving on DB

Tags: magento2, admin, attributes, customer, customer-attribute

I have added a custom customer attribute `on_account`. It is displayed as expected in the admin forms: to create a new customer or to edit an existing one, also when creating an Order with a new customer.

However, when I try to save any customer it gives me the error:
*"On Account" is a required value.*

This is how my tables look like:

**eav_attribute**

```
attribute_id => 248,
entity_type_id => 1,
attribute_code => on_account,
attribute_model => null,
backend_model => null,
backend_type => int,
backend_table => null,
frontend_model => null,
frontend_input => boolean,
frontend_label => On Account,
frontend_class => null,
source_model => Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean,
is_required => 1,
is_user_defined => 1,
default_value => 0,
is_unique => 0,
note => null
```

**customer_eav_attribute**

```
attribute_id => 248,
is_visible => 1,
input_filter => null,
multiline_count => 0,
validate_rules => null,
is_system => 0,
sort_order => 120,
data_model => null,
is_used_in_grid => 0,
is_visible_in_grid => 0,
is_filterable_in_grid => 0,
is_searchable_in_grid => 0,
is_used_for_customer_segment => 0
```

**customer_eav_attribute_website**

```
attribute_id => 248,
website_id => 10,
is_visible => null,
is_required => null,
default_value => null,
multiline_count => null
```

**customer_form_attribute**

```
form_code => adminhtml_checkout,
attribute_id => 248

form_code => adminhtml_customer,
attribute_id => 248
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advanced

Comment: Hello, did you find what was missing? I am facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no meaning to add required for the boolean typ. bcz if it is required then it's value always becomes 1. so is_required should be 0.
2. Use the backend model: Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute\Backend\Data\Boolean
3. Use the backend Type: static, or try with varchar.

maybe this will help you to make your attribute workable.

Comment: Makes sense, especially point 1. But still doesn't save the value